# No me abre el localhost de vite react

Tags: localhost, vite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola tengo un problema y es que al tratar de correr la pagína con el mando "npm run dev" solo me suelta error y no entiendo por qué e borrado y vuelto hacer todos los comandos desde la terminal de git bash pero obtengo siempre el mismo resultado

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el contenido del archivo `2023-01-12T22_35_37_845Z-debug-0.log` que es donde el error te dice que ha guardado el registro de errores. Por favor agrégalo como texto, no como imagen

Comment: Será de ayuda que agregues la salida del comando `npm run`.